# Create C++ Object File Library (.lib) using stubbed functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm trying to create a .lib file to go with an external .dll so we can compile our code against it (VS2010). In this external library functions are declared using __stdcall, they don't specify __declspec(dllimport). Example:

```
extern "C"
{
    int __stdcall exampleFunction(int firstArgument);
}
```

I've tried the following:

### Create .lib from .def

Creating a .def file as follows:

```
EXPORTS
method_1
method_1@16    @1 ; ordinal from dumpbin
...
```

Then creating the .lib from this

```
lib /MACHINE:x86 /def:my_def_file.def OUT:my_library.lib
```

The code links ok but throws a "Privileged Instruction" exception when first invoking a method from the dll.

### Create .lib from .obj

As detailed in this [kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313)  another possibility is to create a set of stub functions, compile them into a .obj file and create the .lib from that. I am however unable to even get the example on the kb page to work, e.g.

```
// my_library.cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void _stdcall Function(void) {}
```

When I run the required commands on this file:

```
CL /c /Ob0 my_library.cpp
lib /def:my_library.obj /MACHINE:x86
```

Then opening my_library.obj does show the string "_Function@0", as expected but my_library.lib shows no trace of this. Furthermore I get some funky warning messages when running the lib command:

```
hasp_api.obj : warning LNK4017: L☺♥ statement not supported for the target platform; gnored
hasp_api.obj : warning LNK4017: ► statement not supported for the target platform; ignored
```

I'm all for peace and love but I'm kinda stuck and its driving me crazy, any help with either of the methods above would be appreciated!

Comment: So the code in the DLL is NOT __delspec(dllexport) 'ed ? but instead is built with a module .def file specifying its exports? is that correct ?

Comment: There is no __declspec(dllexport) nor is there a .def file. I created the .def file i mentioned manually by looking up the function list using dumpbin.

Comment: Although I haven't been able to create a .lib from a .obj file it turned out that creating the .lib from the .def file was perfectly ok, the "Priveleged instruction" error was caused by a bad VS2010 solution file and had nothing to do with this library file.

Comment: Send a letter of gleaming review to MS about the quality control on their solution file integrity. Just. wow.